# Working with Sinch Instant Messaging System

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, sinch

I am using Sinch and Parse for my instant messaging system integrated in our application, and I have two concerns.

1) For some reason, I am receiving the following error when the messaging activity is displayed: The message client did not start". Furthermore, the message does not seem to go through in Sinch and not reflected visually in the application.

Below is the activity code (when the user clicks on the "quick chat" button, it takes them to the messaging activity page.

Below is the activity code for the messaging activity

```
public class MessagingActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection, MessageClientListener {

    private String recipientId;
    private Button sendButton;
    private EditText messageBodyField;
    private String messageBody;
    private MessageService.MessageServiceInterface messageService;
    private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    private ListView messagesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.messaging);

        doBind();


        messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
        messagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        recipientId = intent.getStringExtra("Name");

        messageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBodyField);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMessage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        messageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBodyField);
        messageBody = messageBodyField.getText().toString();
        if (messageBody.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //Here is where you will actually send the message throught Sinch
        messageService.sendMessage(recipientId, messageBody);
        messageBodyField.setText("");
    }

    private void doBind() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MessageService.class);
        bindService(serviceIntent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unbindService(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        //Define the messaging service and add a listener
        messageService = (MessageService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
        messageService.addMessageClientListener(this);
        if (!messageService.isSinchClientStarted()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The message client did not start."
                ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        messageService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageDelivered(MessageClient client, MessageDeliveryInfo deliveryInfo) {
        //Intentionally  left blank
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageFailed(MessageClient client, Message message,
                                MessageFailureInfo failureInfo) {
        //Notify the user if message fails to send
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message failed to send.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onIncomingMessage(MessageClient client, Message message) {
        messageAdapter.addMessage(message, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent(MessageClient client, Message message, String recipientId) {
        messageAdapter.addMessage(message, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushData(MessageClient client, Message message, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        //Intentionally left blank
    }
}
```

I have verified that the APP_KEY, the APP_SECRET and ENVIRONMENT matches what was recorded on Sinch.
I have tried this both on the emulator, and on a physical device.

Thanks in advance

Code service

```
 public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {

        private static final String APP_KEY = "XXXXX";
        private static final String APP_SECRET = "YYYYY";
        private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";
        private final MessageServiceInterface serviceInterface = new MessageServiceInterface();
        private SinchClient sinchClient = null;
        private MessageClient messageClient = null;
        private String currentUserId;

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId().toString();

            if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
                startSinchClient(currentUserId);
            }

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        public void startSinchClient(String username) {
            sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                    .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

            sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

            sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
            sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);

            sinchClient.checkManifest();
            sinchClient.start();
        }

        private boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
            return sinchClient != null && sinchClient.isStarted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
            sinchClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
            client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
            messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
            sinchClient = null;
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (isSinchClientStarted()) {
                sinchClient.stop();
                sinchClient.removeSinchClientListener(this);
            }
            sinchClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return serviceInterface;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
            //Intentionally left blank
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client, ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
            //Intentionally left blank
        }

        public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
            if (messageClient != null) {
                WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
                messageClient.send(message);
            }
        }

        public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            if (messageClient != null) {
                messageClient.addMessageClientListener(listener);
            }
        }

        public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            if (messageClient != null) {
                messageClient.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
            }
        }

        public class MessageServiceInterface extends Binder {

            public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
                MessageService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
            }

            public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
                MessageService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
            }

            public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
                MessageService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
            }

            public boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
                return MessageService.this.isSinchClientStarted();
            }
        }
    }
```

2) Limit: I would like to set a limit, where a only 25 messages would be available between a particular party.

Thanks in advance, and if you need any clarification, let me know.

**Update 3**
When user clicks on this button, he is taking to the MessagingActivity with the person he has been matched to based upon the below criteria

```
 final Button ibutton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnQuickChat);
        idrinks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openConversation();
        }

        private void openConversation() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                        .getObjectId());

                query.setLimit(1);

                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                          if (e == null) {
                               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                               intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                               startActivity(intent);
                           } else {
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                   "Error finding that user",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       }
                    });
                }
    });
```

MessagingActivity (nearly same as one provided in tutorial):

```
public class MessagingActivity extends Activity {

    private String recipientId;
    private EditText messageBodyField;
    private String messageBody;
    private MessageService.MessageServiceInterface messageService;
    private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    private ListView messagesList;
    private String currentUserId;
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
    private MessageClientListener messageClientListener = new MyMessageClientListener();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.messaging);

        bindService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        recipientId = intent.getStringExtra("RECIPIENT_ID");
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

        messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
        messagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        populateMessageHistory();

        messageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBodyField);

        findViewById(R.id.sendButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMessage();
            }
        });
    }

    //get previous messages from parse & display
    private void populateMessageHistory() {
        String[] userIds = {currentUserId, recipientId};
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage");
        query.whereContainedIn("senderId", Arrays.asList(userIds));
        query.whereContainedIn("recipientId", Arrays.asList(userIds));
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> messageList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < messageList.size(); i++) {
                        WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(messageList.get(i).get("recipientId").toString(), messageList.get(i).get("messageText").toString());
                        if (messageList.get(i).get("senderId").toString().equals(currentUserId)) {
                            messageAdapter.addMessage(message, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
                        } else {
                            messageAdapter.addMessage(message, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        messageBody = messageBodyField.getText().toString();
        if (messageBody.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        messageService.sendMessage(recipientId, messageBody);
        messageBodyField.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        messageService.removeMessageClientListener(messageClientListener);
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            messageService = (MessageService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
            messageService.addMessageClientListener(messageClientListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            messageService = null;
        }
    }

    private class MyMessageClientListener implements MessageClientListener {
        @Override
        public void onMessageFailed(MessageClient client, Message message,
                                    MessageFailureInfo failureInfo) {
            Toast.makeText(MessagingActivity.this, "Message failed to send.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onIncomingMessage(MessageClient client, Message message) {
            if (message.getSenderId().equals(recipientId)) {
                WritableMessage writableMessage = new WritableMessage(message.getRecipientIds().get(0), message.getTextBody());
                messageAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessageSent(MessageClient client, Message message, String recipientId) {

            final WritableMessage writableMessage = new WritableMessage(message.getRecipientIds().get(0), message.getTextBody());

            //only add message to parse database if it doesn't already exist there
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage");
            query.whereEqualTo("sinchId", message.getMessageId());
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> messageList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        if (messageList.size() == 0) {
                            ParseObject parseMessage = new ParseObject("ParseMessage");
                            parseMessage.put("senderId", currentUserId);
                            parseMessage.put("recipientId", writableMessage.getRecipientIds().get(0));
                            parseMessage.put("messageText", writableMessage.getTextBody());
                            parseMessage.put("sinchId", writableMessage.getMessageId());
                            parseMessage.saveInBackground();

                            messageAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessageDelivered(MessageClient client, MessageDeliveryInfo deliveryInfo) {}

        @Override
        public void onShouldSendPushData(MessageClient client, Message message, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {}
    }
}
```

MessageService activity

```
public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "61b1bfc0-b82a-44f5-ab68-dedca69ead8c";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "jrFrLr8Adkm0Na4nLdASDw==";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";
    private final MessageServiceInterface serviceInterface = new MessageServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient sinchClient = null;
    private MessageClient messageClient = null;
    private String currentUserId;
    private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;

    private Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.dooba.beta.matchOptionActivity");

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

        if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
            startSinchClient(currentUserId);
        }

        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void startSinchClient(String username) {
        sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

        sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

        sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);

        sinchClient.checkManifest();
        sinchClient.start();
    }

    private boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
        return sinchClient != null && sinchClient.isStarted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", false);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        sinchClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", true);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
        sinchClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return serviceInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client, ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
    }

    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
            messageClient.send(message);
        }
    }

    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public class MessageServiceInterface extends Binder {
        public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
            MessageService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
        }

        public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
            return MessageService.this.isSinchClientStarted();
        }
    }
```

Message adapter activity:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static final int DIRECTION_INCOMING = 0;
    public static final int DIRECTION_OUTGOING = 1;

    private List<Pair<WritableMessage, Integer>> messages;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MessageAdapter(Activity activity) {
        layoutInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        messages = new ArrayList<Pair<WritableMessage, Integer>>();
    }

    public void addMessage(WritableMessage message, int direction) {
        messages.add(new Pair(message, direction));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return messages.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int i) {
        return messages.get(i).second;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        int direction = getItemViewType(i);

        //show message on left or right, depending on if
        //it's incoming or outgoing
        if (convertView == null) {
            int res = 0;
            if (direction == DIRECTION_INCOMING) {
                res = R.layout.message_right;
            } else if (direction == DIRECTION_OUTGOING) {
                res = R.layout.message_left;
            }
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(res, viewGroup, false);
        }

        WritableMessage message = messages.get(i).first;

        TextView txtMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        txtMessage.setText(message.getTextBody());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote the tutorial you're following, and actually just updated it yesterday to fix your first problem. Check out http://tutorial.sinch.com/android-messaging-tutorial/#show-spinner to see the updates. Instead of showing a toast message when the service is not started, the new version will show a progress dialog (loading spinner) until the service has either started or failed to start.

Could you clarify your second question?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and update. In my application I do not however have a ListUsersActivity where you have a list of user that an individual select to chat with. Instead the user goes directly into chat with the person that he has been matched with based around various criteria. For your courteously, I have included the previous activity (the one before the user enters MessagingActivity) under the update section of my initial post. As for the second question, its setting a limit of 25 messages between each conversation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have followed your suggestions and have added the a progress dialog (loading spinner)  to my mattchOptionActivity, and have updated the code under the update 2 section of my initial post. My issue now is that it loads indefinitely, and does not seem to connect with the client.

Comment: Good catch! I realized the progress dialog will only disappear when re-installing the app, since the service is continually running in the background, and won't call onClientStarted each time the app is opened. I'll push out an update to the tutorial ASAP.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the Sinch to be one of the best, and is my prefered, but is just experieicing issues making it work. I think it would also be interesting to establish various criteria like for instance set a limit of messages that can be sent in a conversation, add filtering ability, where a user would not be able to enter numbers, but only alphabetical letters etc.

Comment: In the meantime, what would be your suggested solution?

Comment: Only show the spinner if the sinch client is not started. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. My problem is as follow. The spiner continuously run, and it does not seem to connect.

Comment: Hey - I've updated the source code for the tutorial to be a production-ready messaging app. Please see [the update on this branch](https://github.com/sinch/android-messaging-tutorial/tree/update). The text of the tutorial will be updated within the next few days or so.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and effort. Unfortunately, I have been struggling with this issue for months, and have still been unable to resolve it. I don't understand it, it should be working properly but the message activity just starts with no errors shown but when I type a message it doesn't send and does not seem to connected to sinch. I have included the codes under the update 3 section of my initial post. I would really appreciate if you could look into this as this has been a major headache for me since a while.

Comment: Hey! I got your email & responded.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem! I don't understand why though, you guys seem to have resolved it but for me it doesn't work :\

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your service in manifest. I had the same problem and it solved it.